# trigger oracle 16 age limit

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PREVENT16YRS  

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF compno ON entry

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT compdob
from competitor
where (2018 - EXTRACT(compdob) < 16);
raise raise_application_error( -20001, 'This is a custom error' );
END;
```

Would like to restrict 16 years old from entering into entry table. But there's some syntax error in raising the application error. Some advise would be much appreciated thank you. :)

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive? Please add it to your question. "Some syntax error" is a bit unspecific ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `select` from the target table in a row level trigger. You can simply access the value of the column through the `:new` record. Your select as shown has the additional problem that it would read the entire table, not just the row that was inserted.

To raise an exception, you only use `raise_application_error`. The `RAISE` keyword is only there to re-throw an exception that was handled in an exception handler.

To check if a given date is more than 16 years in the past, you can use `months_between()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PREVENT16YRS  
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF compno ON entry
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if months_between(current_date, :new.compdob) < 16 * 12 then
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Too young!' );
  end;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. !! :)